# TinyMce not showing icons

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, tinymce-5

I am using laravel with blade and Vue.js (the tinymce- wrapper @tinymce/tinymce-vue).

**Problem**:
TinyMce (version 5.7.0) is not showing icons after i switched from cloud to self hosted.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <editor
            tinymce-script-src="/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            v-model="content"
            api-key="no-api-key"
            :init="{
         height: 500,
         menubar: false,
         plugins: [
           'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
           'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
           'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
         ],
         toolbar:
           'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
           alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
           bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
       }"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        'editor': Editor
    },
    data:function(){
        return{
            content:'test'
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Adding

```
import 'tinymce/icons/default'
```

does not help.
**Any clues anyone?**

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded tinymce version 5.3.0 and copied the icons folder from that version into my tinymce folder. The icons get loaded now.

I just wonder why they haven't been included in the version 5.7.0.